# How to use parent class object in multiple child class to use all set variables in parent object in children class in python

Tags: python, class, object-oriented-analysis

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d


temp = A("japan", "Germany")
childtemp1 = B("California")
childtemp2 = C("Delhi")
```

After Sometime i am using class B and C for two different purposes but they both have some same common variables which is present in class A and class A is already instantiated.

I am using this class B and C in some more different classes where i want use variables of both class (A and B) and class (A and C).

Comment: `temp.a` and `temp.b`??? or wherevre you have it, the same ways as always, `.a` and `.b` ... but you never pass `temp`?

Comment: I want to use class B afterwards with all variables like childtemp1.a, childtemp1.b, childtemp1.c .

Similarly, I want to use class C afterwards with all variables like childtemp2.a, childtemp2.b, childtemp1.D .

Comment: In other words, I want to add some more variables to class B and class C. And the variables are coming from object of A

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Are you new to using classes? If you want to pass `temp` to `B` then simply do it. But why is `B` a subclass of `A` when it doesn't inherit anything? Do you want `A` to track all its instances then access them from `B`? [What are you actually trying to accomplish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)?

Comment: I want to instantiate object of A once with "Japan" and "Germany" and use it further for 100 of child classes of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access `a, b, c` using `childtemp1` you need to pass `a, b, c` while creating the object

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.c = c
        A.__init__(self, a, b)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, d):
        self.d = d
        A.__init__(self, a, b)

childtemp1 = B("Japan", "Germany", "California")
childtemp2 = C("Japan", "Germany", "Delhi")
print(childtemp1.a, childtemp1.b, childtemp1.c)
print(childtemp2.a, childtemp2.b, childtemp2.d)
```

**Output:**

```
Japan Germany California
Japan Germany Delhi
```

You can create child class using parent object

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return "a = " + str(self.a) + " b = " + str(self.b) 

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, parent, c):
        self.c = c
        A.__init__(self, parent.a, parent.b)

    def __repr__(self):
      return  super().__repr__()+ " c = " + str(self.c)

class C(A):

    def __init__(self, parent, d):
        self.d = d
        A.__init__(self, parent.a, parent.b)

    def __repr__(self):
        return  super().__repr__()+ " d = " + str(self.d)

temp = A("Japan", "Germany")
childtemp1 = B(temp, 'India')
childtemp2 = C(temp, 'USA')

print(childtemp1)
print(childtemp2)
```

**Output:**

```
a = Japan b = Germany c = India
a = Japan b = Germany d = USA
```

Comment: This is the repeating work we are doing
I want to instantiate object of A once with "Japan" and "Germany" and use it further for 100 of child classes of it.

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you to understand

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def print_variables(self):
        print(self.a , " ", self.b, end = "  ")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
        super(B, self).__init__(a,b)
        self.c = c

    def show(self):
        super(B, self).print_variables()
        print(self.c)

childtemp1 = B("a","b","c")

childtemp1.show()
```

**Output**

```
a   b  c
```

Comment: Why do you do `super(B, self).print_variables` when `self.print_variables` would work?

Comment: To refer conceptually. Otherwise we can also access variables directly like self.a